# Oracle vs Postgres order by

Tags: postgresql, oracle, database-migration

I am running below query in Oracle and Postgres, both shows different output with respect to ordering of the values.

```
with test as (
select 'Summary-Account by User (Using Contact ID)' col1 from dual
    union all
select 'Summary-Account by User by Client by Day (Using Contact ID)' col1 from dual
)
select * from test
order by col1 desc;
```

Below is Oracle one

[image: Oracle output]

Postgres

```
with test as (
select 'Summary-Account by User (Using Contact ID)' col1
    union all
select 'Summary-Account by User by Client by Day (Using Contact ID)' col1
)
select * from test
order by col1 desc;
```

[image: PostgreSQL output]

Oracle collation is AL32UTF8
Postgres has LC_CTYPS is en_US.UTF-8

Both of them look same from how database should behave. How to fix this?

I have read few posts on stackoverflow about POSIX and C, after changing the query order by to **order by col1 collate "C" desc;** The result matches Oracle output.

Is there anyway to apply this permanently?

Comment: "apply this permanently" You mean you want to apply the modification of collation system-wide without having to modify any SQL statements?

Comment: `AL32UTF8` is not a collation it's an encoding. The sorting collation is defined by the values of `NLS_SORT`  and `NLS_COMP`

Answer (score 6):

`AL32UTF8` is not a collation, but an encoding (character set).

Oracle uses the “binary collation” by default, which corresponds the the `C` or `POSIX` collation in PostgreSQL.

You have several options to get a similar result in PostgreSQL:

- create the database with `LOCALE "C"`
- if you are selecting from a table, define the column to use the `"C"` collation:

  ```
  ALTER TABLE tab ALTER col1 TYPE text COLLATE "C";
  ```
- add an explicit `COLLATE` clause:

  ```
  ORDER BY col1 COLLATE "C"
  ```

Comment: The last option could be a performance killer. I would stick with option #1 or #2.

Comment: @TheImpaler Not at all, particularly if you create the correct index.